# ReactJS error: make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning the "clear" ReactJS (i.e. it is not JSX). This is my simple code:

```
(() => {
    class List extends React.Component{
        constructor({tag, attributes, items}){
            super({tag, attributes, items})
            this.tag = tag
            this.attributes = attributes
            this.items = items
        }
        render(){
            return React.createElement(this.props.tag, this.props.attributes, items.map(
                (n, i) => new React.createElement(ListItem, 
                    { attributes: { ...n.attributes, key: i }, value: n.value })))
        }
    }

    class ListItem extends React.Component{
        constructor({attributes, value}){
            super({attributes, value})
            this.attributes = attributes
            this.value = value
        }
        render(){
            return React.createElement("li", this.props.attributes, this.props.value)
        }
    }

    const items = [
        { attributes: null, value: "A" },
        { attributes: null, value: "B" },
        { attributes: null, value: "C" },
        { attributes: null, value: "D" },
        { attributes: null, value: "E" }
    ]

    const root = document.getElementById("root")

    ReactDOM.render(new React.createElement(List, { tag: "ul", attributes: null, items }), root)
})()
```

Pay attention please: I put into the `super` the same parameters that I get in the component's constructor. Also I use `key` for `li` elements. But I get such errors:

> Warning: List(...): When calling super() in `List`, make sure to pass
>   up the same props that your component's constructor was passed.
>
> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop.
>
> Check the render method of `List`.
>
> in ListItem (created by List)
>
> in List
>
> Warning: ListItem(...): When calling super() in `ListItem`, make sure
>   to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was
>   passed.   Warning: ListItem(...): When calling super() in `ListItem`,
>   make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor
>   was passed.   Warning: ListItem(...): When calling super() in
>   `ListItem`, make sure to pass up the same props that your component's
>   constructor was passed.   Warning: ListItem(...): When calling super()
>   in `ListItem`, make sure to pass up the same props that your
>   component's constructor was passed.   Warning: ListItem(...): When
>   calling super() in `ListItem`, make sure to pass up the same props
>   that your component's constructor was passed.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need use a single variable say `props` for example as a paramter of `constructor` function. Then pass it to the `super`. The below code fixed all warnings.

```js
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tag = props.tag;
    this.attributes = props.attributes;
    this.items = props.items;
  }
  render() {
    return React.createElement(
      this.props.tag,
      this.props.attributes,
      items.map(
        (n, i) =>
          new React.createElement(ListItem, {
            attributes: { ...n.attributes, key: i },
            value: n.value
          })
      )
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.attributes = props.attributes;
    this.value = props.value;
  }
  render() {
    return React.createElement("li", this.props.attributes, this.props.value);
  }
}

const items = [
  { attributes: null, value: "A" },
  { attributes: null, value: "B" },
  { attributes: null, value: "C" },
  { attributes: null, value: "D" },
  { attributes: null, value: "E" }
];

const root = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  new React.createElement(List, { tag: "ul", attributes: null, items }),
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```

[Official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) says **Class components should always call the base constructor with `props`**.

When I look at the [source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L388-L395):

```
const hasMutatedProps = instance.props !== newProps;
warningWithoutStack(
    instance.props === undefined || !hasMutatedProps,
      '%s(...): When calling super() in `%s`, make sure to pass ' +
      "up the same props that your component's constructor was passed.",
      name,
      name,
  );
```

It seems react checks if the `props` object it received in the `constructor` function is same object that you passed to base class using `super()` or not. And in your code, it is of-course not the same. What you are passing to the `super({attributes, value})` for example totally a different object. Because in JS:

```
{a: 1, b: 2} === {a:1, b:2} // false
{a: 1, b: 2} !== {a:1, b:2} // true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Destructuring inside render method

```
class List extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props).....

    render(){
        const {tag, attributes, items} = this.props
        return React.....
```